# Removing a splitView Controller from superView

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a split view controller which I am adding as a subview to a dummy view controller and then I am modally presenting the dummy view controller on top of my viewController.It works fine till here:
Code:

```
 ContactsViewController *contactsViewController = [[ContactsViewController alloc]init];


UINavigationController *navController = [[UINavigationController alloc]   


initWithRootViewController:contactsViewController];

MasterViewController* masterViewController = [[MasterViewController alloc]init];

UINavigationController *masterNavigationController = [[[UINavigationController alloc]   

initWithRootViewController:masterViewController] autorelease];

    self.splitViewController.viewControllers = @[masterNavigationController,  
    navController];

 UIViewController *dummyView = [[UIViewController alloc]init];

 [dummyView.view addSubview:self.splitViewController.view];

   self.splitViewController.delegate = detailViewController;

  [self.navigationController presentModalViewController:dummyView animated:YES];

  [contactsViewController release];

  [navController release];
```

Now the problem appears when I try to dismiss the splitView controller(or dummy view) which so appears,whatever I do it just does not work.. any ideas will be very appreciated...

Comment: what problem appears? please show what you tried and what doesn't work

Comment: The view does not dismiss itself. I have tried         [self.navigationController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil]; and [self.navigationController dismissmodalViewControlleranimated:YES];

Comment: I get the following warning in my console:Warning: Attempt to present <UIViewController: 0xa6cf360> on <UITabBarController: 0xb46c610> whose view is not in the window hierarchy! - When trying to present the modal view.